# Is Linux on a VM as safe as Linux installed directly?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, privacy, tor

I often see people saying that it's safer to browse the web via Tor on a Linux machine  rather than on a Windows machine, for privacy reasons.

What I am curious about though is if it's equally "safe" to browse via Tor on a virtual machine running Linux in Windows 8.1. Or will that compromise the privacy?

Comment: Using TOR or the TOR browser does not provide you 100% anonymity.  There are many actions, that can make identifying who was using TOR at a certain time, very trivial.  There is a case of a college student who sent in a bomb threat, this student used TOR and an anonymous email service, the college was able to easily identify who this student was because their access to the college network was the only TOR activity on the network at the time.  TOR is a great proxy, it provides a certain level of anonymity, but at what level depends on the lowest common demonator that can actually identify you.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor browser itself will make you quite anonymous for you to be on the internet. It is said that you are more private when on a linux system because unlike Windows, it does not collect any information about your computer.

When using a VM, the internet is shared from Windows to Linux, so there is possibility of some data leakage (negligible though, since you use Tor) but it is a better idea to dual-boot linux instead of running a Virtual Machine if you want to attain maximum privacy.